# problem with react + vite while running the npm run dev command

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, vite

`npm run dev`

> > client@0.0.0 dev
> > vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\vyask\Desktop\8th sem internship\mern-blog\client\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'vite' imported from C:\Users\vyask\Desktop\8th sem internship\mern-blog\client\vite.config.js.timestamp-1711704484714-33a082f4a0378.mjs
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:854:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:927:18)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

i am trying to run the react app

Comment: Does this error appear on new vite project?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Vite package is missing or not correctly installed in your project. To resolve this issue:

1. Open your terminal.
2. Navigate to your project directory: cd path/to/your/project.
3. Run `npm install vite` to install Vite in your project.

If you already have Vite installed and are still encountering this issue, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file in your project directory, and then run `npm install` to reinstall your packages.